# Getting MD5 hash of the files is terribly slow

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, md5, checksum

I'm using the following code to get a MD5 hash for several files with an approx. total size of 1GB:

```
md5 = hashlib.md5()
with open(filename,'rb') as f: 
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(128*md5.block_size), b''): 
        md5.update(chunk)
fileHash = md5.hexdigest()
```

For me, it's getting it pretty fast as it takes about 3 seconds to complete. But unfortunately for my users (having an old PC's), this method is very slow and from my observations it may take about 4 minutes for some user to get all of the file hashes. This is a very annoying process for them, but at the same I think this is the simplest & fastest way possible - am I right?

Would it be possible to speed-up the hash collecting process somehow?

Comment: Have you tried using larger chunks? Like 1 MB? Might be beneficial with old hard disks. Do you have an SSD (or enough RAM that the data was maybe cached in there)?

Comment: @StefanPochmann No I haven't since bigger chunks will result in more RAM usage. I'm personally having an SSD disk and thats why this method works fine for me, but I can't say the same about the other users having 1GB RAM PC's with the old, slow disks.

Comment: 1 MB is nothing. Do it.

Comment: Good :-) Let me know then. I have an SSD as well, so I can't actually test it, and I'm curious whether / how much faster it is.

Comment: Oh, question: how many files are there?

Comment: @StefanPochmann 61 files, total size: 1,10GB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a fairly weak laptop as well, and I just tried it - I can `md5` one GB in four seconds as well. To go to several minutes, I suspect it's not the calculation but reading the file from hard disk. Try reading 1 MB blocks, i.e., `f.read(2**20)`. That should need far fewer reads and increase the overall reading speed.

Comment: Btw. I have tried it on my HDD hard disk, first run took about 12 seconds to complete, while second run only 2.3 seconds~. Could this be cached somewhere?

Comment: The 2.3 seconds was almost certainly thanks to the file being in RAM. I doubt you have an HDD that can read 434 MB/s. I'm not sure that even exists. Not sure about the 12 seconds. You could try rebooting your PC or filling the RAM up with other stuff before trying the test again.

Comment: Can you tell me which HDD you have?

Comment: It's Seagate ST2000DM001.

Comment: Hmm, that one can apparently read 200+ MB/s sequentially, so the 12 seconds sound reasonable if it does that with small blocks as well. Was that with the 128*md5.block_size btw, or with the suggested 1M blocks?

Comment: It was the 128*md5.block_size for the first three times, then I've changed it to the suggested 2^20.

Comment: Not necessarily. Did you wait for the system to load completely, or was it maybe still busy with getting ready? Mine settles down like a minute after logging in. Also, had you accessed some of your files before your earlier 12 seconds test, so *part* of the 1 GB might've been in cache?

Comment: You can ignore the previous (removed) comment, it was a false result (because I've made a typo: 2*20 instead of 2^20). So, acorrding to the 12 seconds earlier, now (with the 1MB blocks) it takes 7 seconds. Thats better, but still not that fast. Do you think I can increase it to the 2MB blocks or it would be too much? Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Yes, 2MB are alright as well. Your program will take around 10MB anyway and you surely have plenty more RAM. But I doubt it'll help much. Your original size, 128*md5.block_size, at least on my PC, is only 8KB. There's a big difference (or rather factor) between 8KB and 1MB, but not so much between 1MB and 2MB.

Comment: Yeah, like I said. I can't get lower than 7 seconds on my HDD. Thats still a lot. Curious if there is something left I can do, other than that.

Comment: I wouldn't call 7 seconds a lot, you're reading (and processing) a lot of data from HDD, after all. And it's nowhere near the 4 minutes. Btw, any chance those users had the funny idea of doing it from a USB stick? That could also explain the slowness. One more thing you could try is use `readinto`. I've updated [an answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30064243/1672429) with that now.

Comment: It's worth to mention it's 7 seconds for me. While users are complaining about few minutes. There is no chance those users are doing it from the USB stick. My app is a file-patcher based app, so basically all it does is compare the hashes on the local(user) & remote server and download a fresh file if there is a difference.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I understood that 7 seconds was for you, not those users, and I'm looking forward to know what difference the larger buffer makes for them.